# Integration of Derivative Implies Differentiation of the Integral

Tags: analysis

(Differentiation of the Integral) If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is $C^1$ and $F'=f.$

(Integration of the Derivative) If $f$ is $C^1$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^bf'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a).$

How can we prove that the integration of the derivative implies the differentiation of the integral? I want to show that $f(a)=0$ but I'm not finding a way to do so.
Edit: Not sure if showing $f(a)=0$ is the best approach - how can we prove this statement?

Comment: Don't you get that the integral of any function from $a$ to $a$ is $0$ from the limit definition? Since the $\Delta x_i$ must be $0$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Yes, but how does that imply $f(a)=0?$

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused and thought you wanted to show that $F(a) = 0.$ There is no guarantee that $f(a) = 0.$ What were you planning on doing with that anyway?

Comment: @StephenDonovan originally I just saw the two equations we are given and if $f(a)=0$, then we are done.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I think you may be implicitly switching the order of differentiation and integration

Comment: If you already know every continuous function has a primitive then the first FTC follows immediately from the second, but I'm not sure how you intend to prove the first using the second otherwise (since the second FTC requires the existence of a primitive)